# Max date for mat-calendar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was using `<mat-calendar>` long back. I took now and tried to set `maxDate` (i.e) disabling all previous dates. But now I found now support for .

Code

```
   <mat-calendar name="appointment_date" [maxDate]="maxDate"  [selected]="selectDate" (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)">
            </mat-calendar>

maxDate = new Date();
```

I also tried with`[max]` but not working out. Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need check the `maxDate` variable value and format.

I tried to reproduce `[maxDate]` property it worked.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-calendar-ggs5ha

Answer (score 1):

This works for disabling previous dates:

Try this in your html:

```
<mat-calendar name="appointment_date" [min]="minDate" [selected]="selectDate" 
              (selectedChange)="onSelect($event)">
</mat-calendar>
```

And this in your component.ts:

```
  minDate = new Date();
```